# Create Stored Procedure to update field for a new record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in MYSQL that populates a field if left blank while creating the record. Specifically we have an application that uses a CC field to populate e-mail address when a new ticket is created.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cc_update`()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM `ehelpdesk`.`ticket` WHERE `CC` = 'Null';
UPDATE `ehelpdesk`.`ticket` SET `CC`='email@mail.com';

END
```

What i'm not figuring out is how to call the procedure when a new ticket or 'ID' is created.

Here's the full code I used to create the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `ins_cc` BEFORE INSERT ON `ticket` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

IF (NEW.CC IS NULL) THEN
SET NEW.CC='email.string';
End If;
end$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: What you want is a trigger, a function which is called every time a new record is inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a trigger, which is be execute each time a record is inserted to the ehelpdesk table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ticket_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `ticket` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  IF (NEW.CC IS NULL) THEN
    SET NEW.CC= "email@mail.com";
  END IF;

END;
```

For what you are doing, ensure that CC is not null, I 'd suggest setting the default value of ticket.CC to email@mail.com

```
ALTER TABLE `ehelpdesk`.`ticket` 
CHANGE COLUMN `CC` `CC` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'email@mail.com' ;
```

Your stored procedure is not correct

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `cc_update`()
BEGIN
  UPDATE `ehelpdesk`.`ticket` SET `CC`='email@mail.com' WHERE `CC` IS NULL;
END
```

Comment: I tried just changing the default value of the column to the string i want but it still leaves it null, I created the trigger as well but it still seems to be leaving the field null

Comment: @ Binary_Alchemist I added the trigger code, let me know if i'm still missing something but it takes and the trigger has been created.

Comment: Ok so I think the trigger is working now the issue must be with the program it's self.  If the record is created automatically through the program it populates the CC filed but if a technician created a ticket manually it leaves it null regardless.  I'm thinking the app must be entering the value entered by the tech in this case regardless of the database.  Thanks for your help though that solved the majority of my problems.

Comment: @JTuman When a technician enters a ticket, what value is CC in the database?  IS it Null or perhaps a null sting ( '' )?

Comment: The value that ends up hitting the DB is just Null.

Comment: @JTuman You can try replacing `IF (NEW.CC IS NULL)` with `IF( CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.CC) > 0)`